# Center two DIVs, including their content, vertically inside another parent DIV

Tags: html, css

I have two DIVs inside a parent div. I want them to be:

[image]

So I searched for examples of this because it is such a trivial problem. I tried a few examples from SO but it didn't seem to make any difference for my example. I tried vertical-align: middle; and inline-block but without any success. Here is my fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/Sz2fU/1/

HTML

Play A

CSS

```
.parentBox
{
    height: 100px;
}
.left_box
{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background:green;
    float:left;
}
.right_box
{
    width: 18%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background:blue;
    float:right;
}
.inputBox
{
    height:80px;
}
```

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Sz2fU/3/ or 100% width for the parent http://jsfiddle.net/Sz2fU/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is to use `display: table` for the parent div and `display: table-cell` for the children; otherwise, `vertical-align` is not respected.

### JSFiddle: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jonsuh/ULtP4/)

```
.parentBox {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid lime;
    display: table;
}

.left_box,
.right_box {
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.left_box {
    background:green;
}
.right_box {
    width: 18%;
    height: 100%;
    background:blue;
}
.inputBox {
    height:80px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In order for `vertical-align` to work in a `table` we will have to use `table-cell`

**Try this:**

Add `display:table;` and `width:100%;` to `.parentBox`

Remove `float` from `.left_box` and `.right_box`

Add `display: table-cell;` and `text-align:center;` to `.left_box` and `.right_box`

You needed to add `text-align:center;` to center the input to the middle.

## **[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n52v5/2/)**

More info **[here](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.html)** for vertical alignment.

**Note:** IE7 and below do not support `display:table;` or `display: table-cell;`

Answer (score 0):

Add `line-height: 100px` to the parent `div`. `Vertical-align:middle` refers to `line-height`, so setting it up to the height of the block will do the job. Just don't forget to reset `line-height` to normal on children (otherwise, they will be with `line-height: 100px` too and if text in it more than one line you get huge block).